# What does %% in PL/pgSQL mean?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I was reading over [Instagrams sharding solution](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram) and I noticed the following line:

```
SELECT nextval('insta5.table_id_seq') %% 1024 INTO seq_id;
```

What does the %% in the SELECT line above do?
I looked up PostgreSQL and the only thing I found was that %% is utilized when you want to use a literal percent character.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insta5.next_id(OUT result bigint) AS $$
DECLARE
   our_epoch bigint := 1314220021721;
   seq_id bigint;
   now_millis bigint;
   shard_id int := 5;
BEGIN
   SELECT nextval('insta5.table_id_seq') %% 1024 INTO seq_id;

   SELECT FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM clock_timestamp()) * 1000) INTO now_millis;
   result := (now_millis - our_epoch) << 23;
   result := result | (shard_id << 10);
   result := result | (seq_id);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: it sure *looks* like it's being used like mod operator but I thought mod was only one `%`

Comment: My guess is that the particular CMS does not like a single `%` and that the author tried to escape it by doubling it. (or even worse: the CMS escapes it by doubling it on output)

Comment: Normally [`%%` would be a unary operator from `hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) but that doesn't seem to be the case here as pointed out by @pozs. Custom operator in their install, maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *only* place I can think of, where a `%` would be doubled up in standard Postgres is inside the [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function, commonly used for producing a query string for dynamic SQL. [Compare examples here on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format%20execute%20%5Bplpgsql%5D%20%5Bdynamic-sql%5D)

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

> In addition to the format specifiers described above, the special
> sequence `%%` may be used to output a literal `%` character.

Tricky when using the [modulo operator `%`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) in a dynamic statement!

I suspect they are running dynamic SQL behind the curtains - which they generalized and simplified for the article. (The schema-qualified name of the sequence is `'insta5.table_id_seq'` and the table wouldn't be named "table".)  In the process they forgot to "unescape" the modulo operator.
That's what they may actually be running:

```
EXECUTE format($$SELECT nextval('%I') %% 1024$$, seq_name)
INTO seq_id;
```

Comment: Inside of plpgsql, I just used: `seq_id := nextval(sequence_name) % 1024;`

Answer (score 2):

With default installation (on 9.2):

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint %% integer
SQL state: 42883
```

So i would say it could be

- a [custom operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createoperator.html)
- or a typo, and they want to write the modulo operator: `%`

Comment: Typo is the answer. Reading the article, the logic requires the modulo operator in its place. I posted a hypothesis how that might have happened ...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an escaped [modulo operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/functions-math.html) to me.