# Postgres %% in function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

What does the "%%" in this statement mean?

```
SELECT nextval(seq_name) %% 1024 INTO seq_id;
```

And why does Postgres say, when I use it?

```
operator does not exist: bigint %% integer
```

Comment: It's either a typo for the modulus operator (%), or it's an operator defined by an extension you have not installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably, it's an artifact from translating dynamic SQL with `format()`, which requires to double `%` characters. Should be the [modulo operator **`%`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) if translated correctly, which also makes sense for a sharding solution or similar. Effectively, you get numbers cycling from 0 to 1023.

I suspect it's the same as we already dealt with here:

- [What does %% in PL/pgSQL mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865331/what-does-in-pl-pgsql-mean/22870279#22870279)

Comment: Believe this came from the code sample in a blog post from Instagram on their generation of unique ids.  Ran into the same problem.

https://instagram-engineering.com/sharding-ids-at-instagram-1cf5a71e5a5c