# Dynamic SQL with EXECUTE and nested format()

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

I tried doing this with just a normal CTE (no `EXECUTE ... FORMAT`) and I was able to do it.
I basically have a table that has some 5 columns and some data in each column that I wanted to concatenate and such to manifest/generate some data in a new column.

I can do something like this and it works:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, case 
                        when var1 = '' then ''
                        when var2 = '' then ''
                        else '' end, 'adding_dummy_text_column'
             FROM some_other_table sot
             WHERE sot.type = 'java')

             INSERT INTO my_new_table 
                    SELECT *, 'This is the new column I want to make with some data from my CTE' || c.type
                    FROM cte c;
```

So this works as I said. I'll end up getting a new table that has an extra column which a hardcoded, concatenated string `This is the new column I want to make with some data from my CTE Java`

Of course, whatever is in the `c.type` column for the corresponding row in the CTE as it loads the `SELECT` is what gets concatenated to that string.

The problem is, as soon as I start using the `EXECUTE...FORMAT` to make it cleaner and have more power to concatenate/combined different data pieces from my different columns (I have data kind of scattered around in bad formats and I'm populating a fresh new table), **it's as if the FORMAT arguments or the variables cannot detect the CTE table.**

This is how I'm doing it

```
EXECUTE FORMAT ('WITH cte AS (SELECT *, case 
                        when var1 = %L then %L
                        when var2 = '' '' then '' ''
                        else '' '' end, ''adding_dummy_text_column''
             FROM some_other_table sot
             WHERE sot.type = ''java'')

             INSERT INTO my_new_table 
                    SELECT *, ''This is the new column I want to make with some data from my CTE %I''
                    FROM cte c', 'word1', 'word2', c.type
             );
```

OK, so I know I used the empty string `'' ''` in this example and the `%L` but i just wanted to show I had no issues with any of that. Its when I try to reference my CTE columns, so you can see I'm trying to do the same concatenation but by leveraging the `EXECUTE...FORMAT` and using the `%I` identifiers. So, the first 2 args are just fine, its the `c.type` that just no matter what column I try, doesn't work. Also, I removed the `c` alias and didn't get any better luck. It's 100% anytime I reference the columns on the CTE though, as I have removed all that code and it runs just fine without that.

But yeah, is there any work around? I really want to transform some data and now have to do the || for concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```sql
EXECUTE format($f$WITH cte AS (SELECT *, CASE
                        WHEN var1 = %L THEN %L
                        WHEN var2 = ' ' THEN ' '
                        ELSE ' ' END, 'adding_dummy_text_column'
             FROM some_other_table sot
             WHERE sot.type = 'java')

             INSERT INTO my_new_table
                    SELECT *, format('This is the new column I want to make with some data from my CTE %%I', c.type)
                    FROM cte c$f$
           , 'word1', 'word2');
```

There are **two levels**. You need a second `format()` that's executed by the dynamic SQL string that's been concatenated by the first `format()`.

I simplified with **dollar-quoting**. See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

The nested `%` character must be escaped by doubling it up: **`%%I`**. See:

- [What does %% in PL/pgSQL mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865331/what-does-in-pl-pgsql-mean/22870279#22870279)

Generates and executes this SQL statement:

```sql
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, CASE
                        WHEN var1 = 'word1' THEN 'word2'
                        WHEN var2 = ' ' THEN ' '
                        ELSE ' ' END, 'adding_dummy_text_column'
FROM some_other_table sot
WHERE sot.type = 'java')

INSERT INTO my_new_table
SELECT *, format('This is the new column I want to make with some data from my CTE %I', c.type)
FROM cte c
```

Which can be simplified and improved to this equivalent:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_new_table(co1, col2, ...)  -- provide target column list!
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN var1 = 'word1' THEN 'word2'
            WHEN var2 = ' ' THEN ' '
            ELSE ' ' END
     , 'adding_dummy_text_column'
     , format('This is the new column I want to make with some data from my CTE %I', sot.type)
FROM   some_other_table sot
WHERE  sot.type = 'java'
```

About the missing target column list:

- [Cannot create stored procedure to insert data: type mismatch for serial column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700309/cannot-create-stored-procedure-to-insert-data-type-mismatch-for-serial-column/68705067#68705067)

Answer (score 0):

You can one command, create and insert into new table!

```
create table my_new_table as
    select *
            , CASE WHEN var1 = 'hello' THEN 'word2'
                   WHEN var2 = ' ' THEN 'var2 is empty'
                   ELSE ' ' END adding_dummy_text_column
            , format(
                'This is the new column I want to make with some data from my CTE %I', sot.type)
           from some_other_table sot
                where sot.type ='java';
```